# n-th quantile for bivariate variable

Tags: distributions, descriptive-statistics, quantiles, quantile-regression, multivariate-distribution

I generate a 2000 bivariate random samples which are negative correlated. I used np.quantile to generate 10 quantile from this random samples. The related point is marked in the following figure. I am not clear how to explain why this 10-quantile point locate in this  position. The code to perform the simulate is attached as well. Or my question is, it is quite natural to explain the quantile for the one-dimensional distribution. But for the high -dimensional distribution, how to explain its quantile.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
num_samples = 2000
mu = np.array([5.0, 2.0])
r = np.array([
        [  3.40, -2.75],
        [ -2.75,  1.0]       
    ])
rng = np.random.default_rng()
y = rng.multivariate_normal(mu, r, size=num_samples)
quantile_set = np.quantile(y, 0.1, axis=0)
plt.plot(y[:,0], y[:,1], 'b.', alpha=0.25)
plt.plot(quantile_set[0],quantile_set[1],'ro',ms=4.5)
plt.grid(True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html) says

```
axis{int, tuple of int, None}, optional
Axis or axes along which the quantiles are computed. The default is to compute the quantile(s) along a flattened version of the array.
```

So, `axis=0` asks for the 0.1 quantile along the first variable.

There are several proposed definitions for an actual multivariate quantile.  You could take the elementwise quantile, or a quantile based on data depth using triangles or half-spaces or convex hulls, or a point that minimises the sum of absolute values of residuals, or probably a bunch of other things. [This is a useful overview](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Eathens/Geometric-Estimators/intro.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can see how is quantile calculated in the n-dimensional case. However, the thing confused me is that, we can see that the 0.1 quantile for this bivariate (marked with red point) locates outside this bivariate data distribution. I can see how it gets there based on the definition. But whether it make sense statistically, because generally there will have no point sampled from this distribution can correspond to this 0.1 quantile.